# Get min value of a list that has a polygon structure

Tags: python

In a project I have several lists that have polygon values like this:

```
[143788.505, 523767.385, 143788.519, 523767.065, 143791.926 523767.213,  143792.216 523760.528, 143804.22 523761.099, 143803.924 523766.718,  143800.893 523766.573]
```

The first element in the list is a X value the second a Y the third X, fourth Y etc...

If I use a function like this, it will get the min value of the complete list. How can I get the min value for both x and y?

```
def my_min(sequence):
    """return the minimum element of sequence"""
    low = sequence[0] # need to start with some value
    for i in sequence:
        if i < low:
            low = i
    return low
```

Min X will be: 143788.505
Min Y will be: 523760.528

Comment: Why not to use `min` function? `min(my_list[::2])`, `min(my_list[1::2])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Setup***

```
L = [143788.505, 523767.385, 143788.519, 523767.065, 143791.926, 523767.213, 143792.216, 523760.528, 143804.22, 523761.099, 143803.924, 523766.718, 143800.893, 523766.573]
```

---

If you're interested in the coordinates as a whole, you can reshape your list, to group corresponding `X` and `Y` values together into tuples.  You can accomplish this with `zip`:

```
coords = list(zip(L[::2], L[1::2]))
```

```
[(143788.505, 523767.385),
 (143788.519, 523767.065),
 (143791.926, 523767.213),
 (143792.216, 523760.528),
 (143804.22, 523761.099),
 (143803.924, 523766.718),
 (143800.893, 523766.573)]
```

Now to find the coordinate with the minimum `X` and `Y` values respectively, use `min` with a key, and set the key to the element of the tuple you are interested in (0 for `X`, 1 for `Y`):

```
>>> min(coords, key=lambda x: x[0])
(143788.505, 523767.385)              # coordinate with smallest x

>>> min(coords, key=lambda x: x[1])
(143792.216, 523760.528)              # coordinate with smallest y
```

---

If you don't care about the coordinate, and just the value, call `min` on slices of your list:

```
>>> min(L[::2])
143788.505

>>> min(L[1::2])
523760.528
```